# Auto clear browser's history when start project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have dynamic website project created by eclipse. I start website first. After that I change something in my project (Ex: css, js...) and run project again, but my website run with browser's history, although I restart tomcat or deploy project again. Only when I clear browser's history, my project will run as new as. So, How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browsers cache manually, Eclipse can not interact with your browser. Ctrl+Shift+Del in most browsers. You can also download addons like FireBug. They let you disbale the browsers cache permanently.